# Extending an existing regex to drop punctuation after URL links

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have an existing replace that matches http within a text string and creates a working URL from the text.

**Working Example:**

```
var Text = "Visit Gmail at http://gmail.com"
var linkText = Text.replace(/http:\/\/\S+/gi, '<a href="$&">$&</a>');
document.write(linkText);
```

**Output:**

*Visit Gmail at http://gmail.com*

**Problem:**

The problem arises when the link appears at the end of a sentence and the punctuation incorrectly becomes appended to the end of the URL.

Can someone advise on a way of extending my regex (or maybe adding a second replacement after this has been transformed) to overcome this?

I think the right answer will include adding something along the lines of `/\W$/g` to my original regex, but I can't see how this can be applied to just one word within the whole string.

As always, very grateful for any help.

Thanks,
Pete

**Examples of problem links**

- http://gmail.com/.
- http://gmail.com,
- http://gmail.com/?
- http://gmail.com!

All of these should resolve the link to **http://gmail.com**

*Note how some could end in a slash then punctuation and others with punctuation directly after the domain name.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
/http:\/\/(.(?![.?] |$))*/
```

My logic is, if the last char is a dot, or question mark followed by either a space or end of string, you don't need it.

```
var Text = "Visit Gmail at http://gmail.com"
var linkText = Text.replace(/http:\/\/(.(?![.?](?:\s|$)))*./gi, '<a href="$&">$&</a>');
document.write(linkText);
```

Gives

```
"Visit Gmail at <a href=\"http://gmail.com\">http://gmail.com</a>"
```

Edit:

This may be better (it doesn't match white space now)

```
http:\/\/(.(?!(?:[.?](?: |$))))*.
```

Comment: @PeterGross Just be sure to verify it works for a bunch of different links too! It's easy to test something on a small dataset and assume it works for all

Comment: Both regex using '.' will still match white space, ie: `http:// not valid`. Keeping same form, it could be accounted for with \s or \S with `http:\/\/(?:\S(?![.?](?:\s|$)))+` or `http:\/\/(?:\S(?![\/.,?!](?:\s|$)))+`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a negative character class?

/http://\S+[^.,?!]/gi

Comment: I'll test this, but can you help explain. Does this remove the punctuation, terminate the search prior to the punctuation or not match links in this format? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could *account* for trailing unwanted characters, whether stripping them or not.

The replacement for both is capture buffer 1: `<a href="$1">$1<\/a>`

This also asumes you can do lookbehind. though I'm not sure if client side JS can do lookbehind assertions.

Strip unwanted chars

```
/(http:\/\/\S+)(?<![\/.,?!])[\/.,?!]*/
```

Or, leave unwanted characters

```
/(http:\/\/\S+)(?<![\/.,?!])/
```

**Alternate, using lookahead**

Strip

```
/(http:\/\/\S+?(?=[\/.,?!]+(?:\s|$)|\s|$))[\/.,?!]*/
```

Leave

```
/(http:\/\/\S+?(?=[\/.,?!]+(?:\s|$)|\s|$))/
```

Comment: Javascript does not support lookbehinds. My answer makes use of a lookahead however